# build error Cordova projects with Cordova 3.1.0-0.2.0

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans

When I run my app on my android device after I have updated cordova plugins I get:

In the cli:

```
Result: 1
sim-android:
cordova -d run android
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/robin/NetBeansProjects/local/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:684:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/prepare.js:124:15
Preparing android project
Processing configuration changes for plugins.
Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.splashscreen',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.battery-status',
  'org.apache.cordova.contacts',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation',    at Array.forEach (native)

    at Object.handlePrepare (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/prepare.js:122:24)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/prepare.js:93:25
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
  'org.apache.cordova.network-information',    at flush (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
  'org.apache.cordova.globalization',

  'org.apache.cordova.device-motion',
  'org.apache.cordova.dialogs',
  'org.apache.cordova.device-orientation',
  'org.apache.cordova.media',
  'org.apache.cordova.media-capture' ]
/home/robin/NetBeansProjects/local/nbproject/build.xml:272: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 11 seconds)
```

Updating the plugins is the only thing that has been updated for the build to fail.

This is my plugins.properties file.

```
org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler=https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git
org.apache.cordova.geolocation=https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
org.apache.cordova.console=https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git
```

Any help with this would be great, thanks.